# How to disable all animations EXCEPT smooth scroll?

Tags: gnome, wayland, scrolling, accessibility, animations

Under GNOME 43.9 on Wayland, if I go to Settings > Accessibility and disable Enable Animations, this results in disabling smooth scroll, which is the only animation that I find useful. Is there a way to disable all animation EXCEPT smooth scroll?